# Image won't display on Image viewer

Tags: java, jdbc, xampp, blob

I'm trying to experiment with mouse events involving the mouse clicking the image and that image will be displayed to another JFrame inside of the labels. The error seems to be the id of the image and I put error handling to print "No user found with the specified ID"

I use the mouseclick event to direct me to my Imageviewer class

```
    private void lblImageViewMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here
        byte[] img = null;
        try {
            Connection myConn = ConDB.getConnection();
            Statement st = myConn.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='" + id.getText() + "'";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            if (rs.next()) {
                img = rs.getBytes("image_file");
                if (img != null) {
                    APImageViewer view = new APImageViewer();
                    view.setTitle("Image View");
                    view.setVisible(true);
                    view.pack();
                    view.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img);
                    Image im = image.getImage();
                    Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(471, 482, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);

                    APImageViewer.lblImage.setIcon(newImage);

                    // Close the current frame
                    this.dispose();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No image found for the specified user");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No user found with the specified ID");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

and it will direct me to my ImageViewer I also instantiate it so it will be displayed on my label

```
    public void instantiateLblImageView() {
        lblImage = new javax.swing.JLabel(); // Instantiate the lblImageView object
        panelWrapper.add(lblImage, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 40, 530, 280)); // Add lblImageView to jPanel1

    }
```

My Database connection is

```
package Main;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConDB {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        String dbRoot = "jdbc:mysql://";
        String hostName = "localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "humss_db";
        String dbURL = dbRoot + hostName + dbName;

        String hostUsername = "root";
        String hostPassword = "";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection myConn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, hostUsername, hostPassword);
            return myConn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```